# Tomcat and vHost fails on specific subdirectory

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

i try to set my domain as vhost.

My config looks like this:

```
<Host name="example.de"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.example.de</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="example_access" suffix=".log"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/app1" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

This config works with every subdir in the webapps-directory, except for the directory I want. If I try to open the Domain, there is an empty browsertab. (Error 404) But if I call it like www.example.de/app1, the app still works and everything ist fine :/

I don't have any idea :/

PS: It's a clean setup of Tomcat, just extracted and edited the server.xml for the vHost-settings

Comment: Which URL works? Which URL doesn't work? What's the "directory you want"?

Comment: The standard config works, it points to the /opt/tomcat/webapps/ directory,... so the domain I call shows me the Site in the root-dir (The standart Tomcat Page). 

With this config I can call my app with www.example.de/app1.

I delete the standart vHost and add my own, pointing to the .../webapps/app1, try to open www.example.de getting a 404error. 
But can also open www.example.de/app1 and it works.

The vHost-Settings work on every other app in tomcat....

Comment: So `http://www.example.de/app1` works but `http://www.example.de/` returns a 404? Do you have a `ROOT` webapp deployed? If not, I would absolutely expect a 404 when requesting `/`.

Comment: Okay, i deployed the app as ROOT an now, its working :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remember to deploy every application you'd like to appear in a virtual host, including the `ROOT` application. If you don't have a `ROOT` application, there is no "default" application that Tomcat can fall-back to, and your clients will get 404 responses when requesting `/`.